# Is it possible to write a class file that loops over the documentbody?

Tags: tex-core, documentclass-writing

What I would like to achieve is a repeat.cls such that I could write a .tex file

```
\documentclass{repeat}
\begin{document}
foobar
\end{document}
```

and then the document would contain 'foobar' a certain number of times.

Is this possible? I tried to combine `\loop` or `\foreach` with the `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument`, but from what I know now, that approach cannot work as TeX would never really "see" the `\end{document}`.

Comment: Probably not that way. You'd need a macro which would scan the text, but this macro can't "exit" the class file. You'd need a command `\myWeirdLoop` after the `\documentclass`. It would still mess up you document, mainly anything that contains catcode changes. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik could we save the meaning of document (begin and end) and the combine with environ. Plus a macro in the preamble to specify the number of repetitions.

Comment: @daleif Ooh, with egeg's answer I understood it. Sometimes I need a drawing to understand things :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof of concept follows. Don't do it at home.

### `repeat.cls`

```
\ProvidesClass{repeat}
\def\repetitions{5} % default
\DeclareOption*{\edef\repetitions{\CurrentOption}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{environ,xparse}
\let\latexdocument\document
\let\endlatexdocument\enddocument

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewEnviron{document}{
  \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tmpa_tl \BODY
  \latexdocument
  \prg_replicate:nn { \repetitions } { \g_tmpa_tl \par }
  \endlatexdocument
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

### test.tex

```
\documentclass[20]{repeat}
\begin{document}
foobar
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]